# Eloquent Removing Columns

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I'm having a really strange issue with my eloquent query. I have a table called `Calls` which I am joining to `Contacts` and `Companies`. I am trying to reference the column `calls.id` but it has been replaced with the id for `Companies`.

Here is my query:

```
$calls=DB::table('calls')
        ->leftJoin('contacts','calls.contact_id','=','contacts.id')
        ->leftJoin('companies','calls.company_id','=','companies.id')
        ->where('completed','=',false)
        ->orderBy('call_on','asc')
        ->get();

return $calls;
```

I have seen on [Github](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/347) that this seems to be a known bug but no-one has put forward a workaround.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're joining on `conctacts.id` and `companies.id`. I don't see any `calls.id` being referenced in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direction solution to your immediate question is to add a select to your Eloquent query:

```php
$calls=DB::select('calls.* from calls')
        ->leftJoin('contacts','calls.contact_id','=','contacts.id')
        ->leftJoin('companies','calls.company_id','=','companies.id')
        ->where('completed','=',false)
        ->orderBy('call_on','asc')
        ->get();

return $calls;
```

Instead of the default `select *`, explicitly dictate what is returned. However, this can be done a lot more cleanly with Eloquent using models:

```php
Calls::whereHas('companies', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('completed', false);
})->orderBy('call_on', 'asc')->get();
```

In order for this to work you need to setup the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) on the model level:

```php
// App\Calls model:
public function companies() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Companies::class);
}

// App\Companies model:
public function calls() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Calls::class);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of your methods worked. The first one throws a SQL syntax error at `'calls.* from calls'`. I've renamed the table to `appointments` in case there was an issue with the MySQL reserved word `call`, however that is still throwing the same error. Your second method returns `Call to undefined method App\Call::companies()`. What am I missing?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail on the second solution. For the first solution just replace `$calls=DB::select('calls.* from calls')` with `$appointments = DB::select('appointments.* from appointments')`

Comment: I've managed to get your second method sort of working. It still doesn't return the fields from the companies or contacts tables but I think you've put me on the right path. I'm going to go do some more reading. Thanks!

Comment: On `$calls` there you should now be able to access for example `$calls->first()->companies->id`

Comment: Ah! I think that was the missing piece! I understand it a lot better now. BTW I couldn't get the first method to work at all, I kept getting the same syntax error (a problem for another day).